# Dynamic value for a transitioned property in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

I searched for a way to manage the `transition` CSS programmatically at runtime. Therefore I need to change the `top` value in the `transition` relatively at to the behavior of others components.
Is it possible or I am dreaming?

Comment: You can assign the `top` value dynamically but not with pure CSS. You'll need JavaScript and inline styles.

Comment: Yes but the "transitions" setup can remain on css? Can you write a little example??

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/61d01kyp/) is a very very simple one. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Great..it works..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `transition` setup (that is specification of the properties whose change of value should be transitioned) can be done in CSS and we can still dynamically modify the value for those properties.

All that is needed is a  bit of JavaScript to assign the modified value to the element through inline style attributes. The `transition` which is set on the element will apply irrespective of whether the value is changed through a CSS selector or through inline styles.

```js
/* transition after some time so that the effect is visible */
window.setTimeout(function() { 
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.top = '100px'; /* set the top value dynamically */
}, 500);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>Something</div>
```